# Вопрос по ботам телеграм на python

Tags: python, telegram, token, qiwi

Всем добрый день!
Пытаюсь написать бота в ТГ для себя чтобы при запросе показывал балансы моих qiwi кошельков. Пробую писать без SSL только longpool. естественно на русских ip не работает и я поставил на linux его и запустил всю систему через тор. в итоге бот функционирует но когда пытаюсь нажать на кнопку для запроса баланса бот вылетает и пишет следующее
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Посмотрите код мой может я что-то не так делаю. Я новичок в этом и пытаюсь разобраться.

1й вариант:

```
import telebot
import pyqiwi


token = 'ТОКЕН'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)





@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def mes_on_start(message):
    wallet = pyqiwi.Wallet('ТОКЕНкиви', 'НОМЕРкиви')
    balance = wallet.balance()
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, balance)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

2й вариант:

```
import telebot
import pyqiwi


token = 'ТОКЕН'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

wallet = pyqiwi.Wallet('ТОКЕНкиви', 'НОМЕРкиви')
balance = wallet.balance()



@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def mes_on_start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, balance)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Заранее всем спасибо!

Comment: как я понял почему то не даёт доступ к qiwi через тор а если его выключить то просто в консоле на запрос про баланс всё работает...

Comment: а можно самого бота пустить через тор а саму функцию КИВИ через RU прокси?

Answer (score 0):

Вам не нужно подключать Tor к общей системе, нужно лишь установить соединение с Telegram через Proxy. Библиотека Telebot содержит нужный модуль 'apihelper', который предоставляет возможность подключения через Proxy.

```
from telebot import apihelper

apihelper.proxy = {'http':'http://10.10.1.10:3128'}
```

Также имеется поддержка и Socks5 (https)

```
apihelper.proxy = {'https':'socks5://userproxy:password@proxy_address:port'}
```

Источник: [github](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#proxy)